# Accessing the request format in a custom API Platform Processor?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

My `POST /api/qr-codes` operation uses a custom processor named `QrCodeProcessor`. I need to inspect the request format in order to further do do some custom logic, before returning the response (no need to use the serialization feature):

```php
class QrCodeProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function process(
      mixed $data, 
      Operation $operation,
      array $uriVariables = [],
      array $context = []
    ) {
        // Access the request to do further processing before returning
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

This seems quite impossible to me. On the other side, using a custom controller is discouraged, so I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Can you not use the requestStack?

Comment: @Bossman It's generally not a good idea. I think that API Platform should provide it by default. For now i'll use listeners to populate my DTO ($data here) with request attributes!

Comment: What do you mean it's not a good idea? The requestStack is a component to be used by design so you can access the request data. There is nothing sinister about it.